# React changes not visible in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a good history playing with react. But today I faced a very strange issue.

I have a hamburger which receives a list of values and the one of the values is selected which I send from the parent through `this.refs.child1.setValues()`. this `setValues` function calls `setState` and that one value is selected through `className` parameter in react.

So in the first step I select first value among 20 values.

the react tab shows this about the first li element:

```
className="{something} +class1"
```

rest all elements have:

```
className="{something}"
```

which is fine. ('class1' is the class which is added dynamically on setstate) and the dom shows first value selected and the rest unselected.

now problem is in the second step as I select another value say 3rd one, so first value should get deselected and 3rd should be selected and the expected react values for 3rd should be

`className="{something} + class1"` and for the rest its showing `className="{something}"`

which is working fine in the react tab BUT in the elements tab both the li elements are getting selected as they both have class1 but class1 should be only with the 3rd element not with the first one (which was previously selected)

Comment: so the problem is react tab and elements tab (DOM) are not in sync for the className parameter

Comment: You don't use "{}", just use {}

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you post the relevant code of the Child component

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Sir, its just an example not an exact code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since React works by using the Virtual DOM, it only makes changes in the DOM to elements it detects a change to. So, since you're never actually removing a class from the first element, it never does a rerender of it, it only rerenders the third one because that's the only one you actually changed.

You need to do something like this:

```
removeClass() {
    let allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.something');
    allLinks.map((link) => link.classList.remove('class1'));

    //and here just call the function to add the class to the right 
    //element.
}
```

Comment: so you mean if I have a value className={"class1 class2"} and then I setState so that  new className={"class1"} , but it (DOM) wont change ( this is exactly what is happening).

Comment: @PalashChordia What I mean is that if you add a new class to the 3rd link with setState, it will not remove the class from the first one because it will only rerender the third link. So first you have to remove the class from all the links and then add it to the correct one, you can do that with the solution I wrote above.